# calculate probabilities of transition states

Tags: probability, transition-matrix

Assume we have the following sequence of states:

```
A-B-C-D
A-B-D-E
A-C-E
A-B-C-E
A-B
B-E
A-D-E
A-C
```

where we have input states `A` and `B`, output states `D`,`E`,`B` and `C`, as well as transitional states `A-B`, `B-C`, `C-D`, `B-D` etc.

So, I can calculate the number of the states and determine probability of the state, for example:

- input state `A` occurs 7 times out of 8, thus the probability of input state `A` is:

  (7*100)/8=87.5%
- transition state `A->B` occurs 4 times, therefore its probability 50%.

However, I am not sure about the right way to calculate the repetitive states, for example:

```
A-B-C-C-C-C-C-D
A-B-D-E
A-C-E
A-B-C-C-C-C-E
A-B-C-C
B-E
A-D-E
A-C
```

In this case, the state `C->C` preserves 8 times, with the probability (8*100)/8=100% ? Which IMHO does not make sense. Obviously I'm doing something wrong.

**UPDATE**

I'm trying to implement ideas from [this paper](https://drakkar.imag.fr/IMG/pdf/1569811033.pdf) section III in particular. I've written a script which parses large number of `pcap` files containing TLS sessions, the result of the script is a list TLS session states, kind of a *graph* of states.

Now, the above mentioned paper says:

*The transition probability between states is derived from frequencies observed in the sequences [...]*

So, the transition probability is what I need to compute. If there's already a `python` library that would do this for me, it'd be ideal :)

I would appreciate if someone would shed some light for me. Thanks!

Comment: Let's start with the first one. You have 7 inputs of A. Four of them transition to B. That is $\dfrac{4}{7} \approx 57.14\% > 50\%$. Next, in your example, $C$ is a transition state 11 times and a terminal/output state twice. Out of the 11 times it is in a transition state, it transitions to C 8 of those times. So, $\dfrac{8}{11} \approx 72.73\%$.

Comment: Are you trying to find point estimates for the transition probabilities given a list of transitions? These will have large variance due to the small sample size and thus are of dubious value.

Comment: @InterstellarProbe and Math1000, thanks for your feedback. I updated my questions, hope it is more clear now, what I want.